# How to get traceroute on cygwin?

Tags: package-management, cygwin, traceroute

The implementation of traceroute(tracert) differs on Windows and Unix. I wanted to compare both with Wireshark. I am on Windows 7 now and I wanted to get Unix traceroute implementation quickly.

My first idea was to get it using MSYS or Cygwin. I installed Cygwin with "inetutils*" packages checked, but there is no traceroute command and corresponding executable in `/usr/bin/`.

I also tried searching for "traceroute" with [Cygwin package search](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=traceroute&arch=x86_64) and found this substring in list of "zsh" files. I installed zsh and tried `traceroute` and `tcptraceroute` with no results.

Which package should i check for installation of traceroute and is there traceroute for Cygwin at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, as Stephen Kitt said there is no ready to use traceroute binaries for Cygwin. That's why i tried to compile it myself.

I can see there is [modern traceroute](http://traceroute.sourceforge.net/) but from it's description follows, that it can't be used with old Linux kernels and for me compilation stuck on missing "dccp.h" and i gave up.

I was able to compile [the old implementation](ftp://ftp.ee.lbl.gov/traceroute.tar.gz), but it works like it can not see ICMP replies on TTL exceeded (there are asterisks instead of results):

> 1  * * *
>
> 2  * * *

Maybe it requires some fixes to work on Cygwin and that's is the reason why there is no traceroute package for Cygwin.

I checked with Wireshark and see it uses UDP test packets and corresponding ICMP replies are delivered correctly. I want to notice that this old traceroute works slowly like Win's `tracert` ("querying" nodes one by one). Modern traceroute gives results very quickly.

Answer (score 18):

There is no `traceroute` in the Cygwin packages, because `tracert` is always available on Windows. See https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2005-12/msg00443.html for a thread briefly discussing this. You can try compiling a Unix-style `traceroute` from source usign Cygwin.

If you want to compare Windows-style `tracert` to Unix-style `traceroute` though, I'd recommend running `traceroute` on Unix or Linux, because the network stacks are different; so running a Unix-style `traceroute` on Windows won't give you quite the same network traces as Unix-style `traceroute` on Unix.

Comment: `ping` also exists on Windows, but is availible for Cygwin :) Anyway, thanks for your answer. Maybe i will try to compile `traceroute` for Cygwin manually.

Comment: Fair point, and `traceroute` offers quite a few more features than `tracert`.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to build a port of `mtr` in Cygwin32 using instructions:

https://github.com/traviscross/mtr/

MTR is an alternative open source traceroute tool. It has both a GUI and Ncurses text interface. It is not exactly the classic traceroute, but I like it more.

Comment: Hello I tried to compile mtr on cygwin64 but there was an error I found solution to add "#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500" into /usr/include/w32api/mprapi.h and file has compiled, I moved mtr.exe to /bin and tried to run it like mtr google.com but there is such error: "mtr: Failure to start mtr-packet: Invalid argument" any idea what I could do to manage latest mtr working in latest cygwin? I also tried older mtr but no success.

Comment: It's been a while and I don't have Cygwin in my new computer, I moved to WSL. That being said, I think you had to run as Administrator for it to work.

Comment: Sure I thought about that and run it with admin rights :) didn't help.